# IE9 Popup window hiding on hover/focus

Tags: javascript, html, primefaces, internet-explorer-9

I have got a primefaces button with an onclick that calls a function with this in it:

```
popup = window.open(urlToOpen, windowName, params);
if (!popup.opener) {
    popup.opener = self;
}
popup.focus();
```

And then the popup shows but as soon as I hover(I'm not clicking!) over any primefaces button in the parent window the popup loses focus.

Does anyone have any idea why this problem might occur?

Answer (score 0):

Check if some button or html element have mouseover callback with focus() in it.

Comment: I can not find any mouseover callbacks with focus(). The thing is that the problem doesn't occur every time so I do not think that could be the problem.